# VSCode Pylint Error - "No name 'appengine' in module 'google'pylint(no-name-in-module)"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

While working with Google Cloud Platform on Visual Studio Code, facing import error issues for appengine packages.

Tried adding `python.venvPath`, `python.autoComplete.extraPaths`. No help.

[Import Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exLB7.png)

Comment: Did you select the appropriate Python environment where you installed the `appengine` package in VS Code?

Comment: Yes, I selected the appropriate Python environment along with the correct virtual environment. 
From what I have learned it is a problem with pylint and using correct pylint version but haven't been able to solve the problem.